# Video Teletype (int 0x10 / ah=0xE) mistakenly repeated by Qemu

Tags: assembly, x86-16, qemu, bootloader, bios

I'm trying to reproduce the qemu hello-word example from [the post](https://medium.com/@g33konaut/writing-an-x86-hello-world-boot-loader-with-assembly-3e4c5bdd96cf). The code doesn't seem to have much room for bugs:

```
# boot.asm
.code16 
.global init       # makes our label "init" available to the outside 
init:              # this is the beginning of our binary later. 
  mov $0x0e41, %ax # sets AH to 0xe (function teletype) and al to 0x41 (ASCII "A") 
  int $0x10        # call the function in ah from interrupt 0x10 
  hlt              # stops executing 
.fill 510-(.-init), 1, 0 # add zeroes to make it 510 bytes long 
.word 0xaa55       # magic bytes that tell BIOS that this is bootable
```

But after compiling it and loading it with qemu:

```sh
as -o boot.o boot.asm
ld -o boot.bin --oformat binary -e init boot.o
qemu-system-x86_64 boot.bin
```

the character 'A' is printed multiple times:
[image]

I've repeated the experiment multiple times. Mostly it behaves normally and only prints the character once. Sometimes it repeats the character 2 or 3 times. The screenshot shows a rare but existing behavior.

Does anyone have an idea how this could happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disable interrupts before you `hlt`.  The `hlt` instruction simply waits for the next interrupt.  On boot, interrupts happen every couple milliseconds.

Comment: @fuz: It's nicer to use an infinite loop (like `.die: hlt` and `jmp .die`). Disabling IRQs doesn't disable things like NMIs and therefore isn't a "100% bullet-proof" solution; but it does disable keyboard IRQ and prevent you from using "control+alt+delete" to reboot (which can make it annoying).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I've summarized your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let me summarize fuz's and Brendan's comments.

The code was wrong because `hlt` halt the cpu only until the next interrupt. When the next interrupt arrives, the cpu resumes and continues running garbage codes (here: 0x00 0x00 ... 0x00 0x55 0xaa 0xrandom-garbage), in which the machine code for `int` might appear and get executed, thereby repeat the printing of 'A'.

The correct way of halting the cpu, as suggested by Brendan, is to put the `hlt` instruction into an infinite loop:

```
.die
hlt
jmp .die
```